# Need to make this JQuery image slider pause on mouseover

Tags: jquery, mouseover

I would like the slide show to pause on mouseover and then begin again when the user takes the mouse off the image. I came up with makeshift way but it caused the timing of the images to go crazy if you moused on and off the image too fast.

```
function theRotator() {
//Set the opacity of all images to 0
$('div.rotator ul li').css({opacity: 0.0});

//Get the first image and display it (gets set to full opacity)
$('div.rotator ul li:first').css({opacity: 1.0});

//Call the rotator function to run the slideshow, 6000 = change to next image after 6 seconds

setInterval('rotate()',6000);
}
function rotate() { 
//Get the first image
var current = ($('div.rotator ul li.show')?  $('div.rotator ul li.show') : $('div.rotator ul li:first'));

if ( current.length == 0 ) current = $('div.rotator ul li:first');

//Get next image, when it reaches the end, rotate it back to the first image
var next = ((current.next().length) ? ((current.next().hasClass('show')) ? $('div.rotator ul li:first') :current.next()) : $('div.rotator ul li:first'));

//Set the fade in effect for the next image, the show class has higher z-index
next.css({opacity: 0.0})
.addClass('show')
.animate({opacity: 1.0}, 1000);

//Hide the current image
current.animate({opacity: 0.0}, 1000)
.removeClass('show');

};


$(document).ready(function() {      
//Load the slideshow
theRotator();
$('div.rotator').fadeIn(1000);
$('div.rotator ul li').fadeIn(1000); // tweek for IE
});
```

Comment: This is not: pleasemakemyscript.com   What have you tried?

Comment: lol I know sorry I'm very new to JQuery this is a project for school. I got the images to pause just fine by adding a Boolean to caused them to stop. Then I tried to start the same function again but it makes the speed change even know I called the same function 
    $('img').mouseout(function(event) {
  foo = true;
 setInterval('rotate()',myInterval);
 });

Comment: look at using `stop()`  http://api.jquery.com/stop/

Answer (score 0):

You should listen to the `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` event, and stop and restart your interval.

Assuming you have a bit of code like

```
<script>
    // Declare the var that will keep reference of the setInterval
    intervalPlay = false;
</script>

<div id="yourSliderContainer">
    // your slide content
</div>
```

You should stop the setInterval when the mouse enter in the div

```
$("#yourSliderContainer").mouseenter(function(mouseEvent) {

    // Stop the setInterval if existing
    if (intervalPlay != false)
    {
        clearInterval(intervalPlay);
        intervalPlay = false;
    }
});

$("#yourSliderContainer").mouseleave(function(mouseEvent) {

    // Restart the setInterval
    if (intervalPlay == false)
        intervalPlay = setInterval('rotate()',6000);
});
```

Note: Maybe the timing of your slide go crazy because your are not stopping setInterval, but recreate, so after some time you have a lot of interval running.

see here for more information : [clearInterval](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_clearinterval.asp)

Comment: intervalPlay = setInterval(rotate,6000); is better. Using alias hover() for mouseenter/mouseleave  is still better. BTW your are using mouseenter handler twice , one should be mouseleave

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your help! Here is the code in case someone else finds this thread. The code below pauses the slider on mouseenter and starts were it left off on mouseleave without any problems (here is the site that I got the code from before I edited it for starts and stops) 
http://www.alohatechsupport.net/webdesignmaui/maui-web-site-design/easy_jquery_auto_image_rotator.html

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery        /1.3.2    /jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var myInterval = 5000;
var intervalPlay = true;


$('div.rotator').mouseenter(function(mouseEvent) {
// Stop the setInterval if existing

if (intervalPlay != false)
{
    clearInterval(myInterval);
    //$(".show").stop();
    intervalPlay = false;
}
});

$("div.rotator").mouseleave(function(mouseEvent) {
// Restart the setInterval
if (intervalPlay == false)
    intervalPlay = true;
});

function theRotator() {
//Set the opacity of all images to 0
$('div.rotator ul li').css({opacity: 0.0});

//Get the first image and display it (gets set to full opacity)
$('div.rotator ul li:first').css({opacity: 1.0});

//Call the rotator function to run the slideshow, 10000 = change to next image      after 6 seconds

setInterval('rotate()',myInterval); 
    }

    function rotate() {
if (intervalPlay == true){
//Get the first image
var current = ($('div.rotator ul li.show')?  $('div.rotator ul li.show') :        $('div.rotator ul li:first'));

    if ( current.length == 0 ) current = $('div.rotator ul li:first');

//Get next image, when it reaches the end, rotate it back to the first image


    console.log(intervalPlay);
   console.log(myInterval);
 var next = ((current.next().length) ? ((current.next().hasClass('show')) ?      $('div.rotator ul li:first') :current.next()) : $('div.rotator ul li:first'));

//Set the fade in effect for the next image, the show class has higher z-index
next.css({opacity: 0.0})
.addClass('show')
.animate({opacity: 1.0}, 1000);

//Hide the current image
current.animate({opacity: 0.0}, 1000)
.removeClass('show');

}
 };

 $(document).ready(function() {     
//Load the slideshow
 theRotator();
$('div.rotator').fadeIn(1000);
$('div.rotator ul li').fadeIn(1000); // tweek for IE
});

</script>
```